# Ubuntu 20.04 Asus Zenbook 14 UX425EA-BM701TS Not able to change brightness. /sys/class/backlight empty

Tags: 20.04, display, intel-graphics, asus, brightness

I have tried various approaches including xbacklight(and other guides online to change it) but nothing worked.

**xrandr** command gives me `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

```bsh
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

gave the following output

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:603e000000-603effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

I have intel iris xe graphics.

I had initially tried installing elementary os Hera. I wasn't able to make brightness control work and then I decided to try ubuntu 20.04. In elementary sys/class/backlight had a folder called asus-nb-wmi. In ubuntu its completely empty. Is this because there are no drivers available for my laptop graphics/video?

Output for
`bash sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'`
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tDXnCvGBDJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `glxinfo -B` or `inxi -G` to check whether the graphics card is actually loaded. If not, you could refer to this question [Ubuntu 20.04 no driver loaded for Intel Iris Xe Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/q/1299067/1156482), where the solution is to upgrade ubuntu to 20.10

Comment: I had to upgrade to 20.10 and it worked. Thanks!