# Ubuntu 20.04 no driver loaded for Intel Iris Xe Graphics

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I set up a dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04 for Asus ZenBook UX393EA, which has an integrated graphics card 'Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics'. However I find llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) is used but not the integrated graphics card.

I believe some other issues are due to this, such as:

- `xrandr` failed to get size of gamma for output default
- the screen resolution can only be set to one value
- no control bar for screen brightness

---

Here are some info:

- linux kernel

```
➜  ~ uname -r 
5.4.0-56-generic
```

- lspci

```
➜  ~ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA   
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:13e2]
    Kernel modules: i915
```

- inxi

**(as you can see, the driver for Intel graphics is not loaded)**

```
➜  ~ inxi -G  
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
           Device-2: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting resolution: 3300x2200~90Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.0-devel (git-3f0da80 2020-12-10 focal-oibaf-ppa)
```

- glxinfo

```
➜  ~ glxinfo -B
name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 21.0.0
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 15694MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.0.0-devel (git-3f0da80 2020-12-10 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.0.0-devel (git-3f0da80 2020-12-10 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.0.0-devel (git-3f0da80 2020-12-10 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

- lshw

```
➜  ~ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:603e000000-603effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

- dmesg

```
➜  ~ dmesg | grep drm 
[    1.420124] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    1.428692] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    1.428949] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    1.667732] [drm] Your graphics device 9a49 is not properly supported by the driver in this
```

where the last one log is:

```
[drm] Your graphics device 9a49 is not properly supported by the driver in this
kernel version. To force driver probe anyway, use i915.force_probe=9a49
module parameter or CONFIG_DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE=9a49 configuration option,
or (recommended) check for kernel updates.
```

there's another log concerning i915, I'm not sure if it's related:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

---

I guess the root cause is that the graphics card is not supported by the current driver i915. I don't know what to do or if there are other reasons for this issue. Here are what I have tried:

- changed /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to "", as the way in [Ubuntu 20.04 Intel HD 615: No Brightness control or no Boot / Stuck on Boot Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252416/ubuntu-20-04-intel-hd-615-no-brightness-control-or-no-boot-stuck-on-boot-scre)
- configure xorg to prefer the Intel or disable modeswitching out of IGD, as the way in [Ubuntu 18.04 not working with Intel Integrated Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062967/ubuntu-18-04-not-working-with-intel-integrated-graphics)
- remove xserver-xorg-video-fbdev, as the way in https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=287323, which only made the boot procedure stuck in splash screen.

None of them works for me. I would be grateful if someone could give any help or ideas.

Comment: I think this article will help you with this: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/iris-xe-max-graphics/index.html

Comment: Did everything else work as expected with Ubuntu on this model of the ZenBook?

Comment: @matanster In my circumstances, everything works fine with Ubuntu 21.04 except for  [suspend issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299312/ubuntu-20-10-nvme-i-o-timeout-after-suspend-exit?noredirect=1#comment2407185_1299312) and [bluetooth issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1929326), both of which have been reported and solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything that I’ve read about the Intel Xe graphics points to it needing a more current kernel than 20.04 currently offers. You will likely need to upgrade to 20.10 to get the most out of your new system.

Comment: Cool, it really works by upgrading to 20.10. Hopefully this won't bring me other issues. Thanks for your help. Btw, is there some way to look up whether a graphics card is supported by a specific kernel version?

Answer (score 18):

I just got a new Asus Zenbook (UX425EA) yesterday which comes with 11th Gen i7 Processor + Intel Iris Xe Graphics, and I was facing the same problem too. After hours of google and scrolling through threads, I found one final fix which resolved the issue once and for all. You'll require the [Ubuntu OEM kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel). **Make sure to enable secure boot in the BIOS** (last time I tried installing it without enabling the secure boot, the screen turned black with weird distortions, so I guess it will be an important step).

The following command does it all:

```
apt install linux-oem-20.04 && sudo reboot 0
```

If you have Intel Iris Xe MAX graphics, things get more complicated, refer here -> https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/iris-xe-max-graphics/index.html.
This should do the job, but if it doesn't make sure that you have the packages as mentioned here -> https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.html.

Hope this helps somebody. :)

Comment: Couldn't thank you enough. I was struggling for hours before i found this. Thank you so much for the fix.

Comment: Thank you! I spent a couple hours troubleshooting this problem on a brand new Dell XPS 8940 running Ubuntu 20.04. After installing the OEM kernel and rebooting I now have both monitors working.

Comment: I wonder if other than this everything worked out of the box for you people when/if installing Ubuntu 20.04 on the ZenBook UX series (switching to a special kernel sounds a little horrific for compatibility with various libraries and version updates to me). Thanks in advance for any info!

Comment: Same issue with Lenovo Ideapad 5i Pro (2021) running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Tried `apt install linux-oem-22.04`, but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Find available `apt search linux-oem`. Install `sudo apt install linux-oem-**.**`. Then reboot worked for me on _22.10_ _Intel Corporation Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]_ HP laptop

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your kernel to 5.8 using:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```