# Ubuntu 20.10 How to use iris driver with intel Iris Xe graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, 20.10, gpu-driver

I've read some questions, like #1297875, but finally not found how to replace graphics driver **i915** with the **iris** driver on Ubuntu 20.10 running on a i7-1165G7 that bring a Intel Iris Xe Grahpics `PCI id [8086:9a49]`.

- Should I use [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) ?
- some changes in X11 config ?
- Or perhaps I misunderstand... kernel use i915 and iris driver is only for user-space OpenGL with MESA ... As I read at https://linuxreviews.org/Intel_Iris

Any idea please ?
Thanks.

#### UPDATE after installed oibaf drivers

I miss understand something ... As we can see below, the **i915** driver is used but for **OpenGL** it is a "Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)"...

```
$ inxi
CPU: Quad Core 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 (-MT MCP-) 
 
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Iris Xe Graphics [8086:9a49]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
 
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: Chicony Chicony USB2.0 Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1: 1600x900 2: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-629e834 2021-05-15 hirsute-oibaf-ppa)
```

After reading this page at intel.com [Intel® Iris® Xe MAX Graphics with Linux](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/iris-xe-max-graphics/index.html) it seems "normal" that driver "i915" is used for Xe Graphics as they say:

> While support for the Intel Iris Xe Graphics processor has already been integrated into Linux* and integrated into Linux-based distributions such as Ubuntu 20.04.1, enabling work for the Intel Iris Xe MAX graphics processor in Linux* is ongoing.

Comment: Another solution given at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics is to use Ubuntu OEM kernel. I did not try yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who run's into this topic, for me, the solution was to go for option 1 - the drivers maintenend by oibaf - and my problem (joining screens with my ASUS VivoBook, running Ubuntu 20.10) was solved.

Roger

Comment: Thanks @Roger.
note: oibaf drivers are installed after an "apt upgrade"

Comment: But after upgrade the driver is still "i915" ...
`$ lsmod|grep video` -> `video   49152  1 i915`