# Ubuntu only starts in nomodeset

Tags: startup, nomodeset

My Ubuntu Ubuntu (20.04.2 LTS) only starts in nomodeset. I believe it is a graphic card issue, but I do not know how to fix it. I have an intel graphic card on an HP laptop. Reinstalling Ubuntu did not help. Should I reinstall my graphic driver? and if yes, how?

My laptop model is HP Pavilion 15-eg0097nr.

lspci | grep VGA shows my VGA as "Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)"

Thank you very much!

Comment: What model number is your laptop? What Intel integrated graphics model do you have (you can find this out by running `lspci | grep VGA` in a terminal)?

Comment: Can you edit the original question to add this information?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel` I had the same Problem because of this package.

Comment: @galexite: I did. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this link to another question here at Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309561/ubuntu-20-10-how-to-use-iris-driver-with-intel-iris-xe-graphics) will help you. It seems oibaf provides a solution.

Comment: @nobody I removed it using
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
It did not solve the issue.

Comment: @guiverc: I am not sure. I downloaded the LTS version of Ubuntu (20.04)

Comment: Please correct your question then, Ubuntu Core 20 has a 10 year supported life like all *year* format releases; which is longer than LTS provides (thus LTS isn't mentioned) but 20 implies it's a *snap* only product and not a 20.04 or *year.month* system.  Ubuntu has both products that use the *year* format (20) and *year.month* (20.04) but they're not the same.   (if your question *issue* is removed; I can remove my comment)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you very much for correcting my mistake. I fixed it.