# blink black screen after start-up

Tags: screen

I have a new HP laptop 15s-2000 series, with an I5 Pentium 11th gen. and a 512GB SSD. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it and after it loads and gets to the desktop image (after 5-6 sec) it blinks a black screen for max 1s, The refresh rate is at 60hz and it does the same at every rate. Beside that blink there is no other problem regarding video (no fluctuation of light, color, no screen gliches).

At the same time, the keyboard does not respond for about 10-15s after desktop loads, after that it works normally. The same after hibernation, when it comes to the screen with the time, where it tells you to press any key, the keyboard does not responds for about 10s, after that it presses and it goes to the login screen. The touchpad works during this time.

My question is:
a) is it a driver thing, this model beeng newer than Ubuntu 20?
b) is it a refresh thing at that point, or a loading time (Ubuntu loading in 14s)?
c) is it a hardware problem with it?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a driver issue, can you use `nomodeset` and try to install your GPUs drivers?

Comment: Had a similar problem once with a brand new Thinkpad. Try getting Ubuntu 20.10 or newer, backported kernels. It helped me-

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this post: [Ubuntu 20.04 no driver loaded for Intel Iris Xe Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics)

I used this comand and there is no blink now.
apt install linux-oem-20.04 && sudo reboot 0

Comment: It solves that problem, but causes others in regard to display comands.