# Brightness Control/xrandr Errors in 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, dell, brightness, intel

I want to adjust the brightness on my laptop, which is currently fixed at the highest brightness.

**My specs:**

- Dell XPS 13 9310 OLED laptop, Ubuntu 18.04 (can't upgrade at the moment)
- Graphics card: 0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 03)
- Kernel version: 5.4.0-90-generic

**Did not work:**

- adding `acpi_osi`, and/or `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'`, to the `/etc/default/grub` at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
- Replacing`#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` with `GRUB_GFXMODE=3456x2160`
- installing the`icc-brightness` package
- installing the`brightness-controller` package
- Tried running the repo at https://github.com/MuDiAhmed/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019, but having issues with `xrandr` as mentioned below.

**Worked...a little?**

- added `acpi_backlight=vendor` to  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

  - did make the brightness bar appear in the GUI, and enabled the keyboard brightness buttons, but the brightness still doesn't change.

**Is it a `xrandr` issue?**

I've tried to solve this using `xrandr` commands as some have had success with.

- Dell's mentions this issue ([dell issue url](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000129708/can-t-change-the-oled-s-brightness-on-precision-xps-systems-once-you-ve-installed-ubuntu-linux)), but on running  `xrandr`  to test I get:

  ```bsh
  xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
  Screen 0: minimum 3456 x 2160, current 3456 x 2160, maximum 3456 x 2160
  default connected primary 3456x2160+0+0 0mm x 0mm
     3456x2160     89.00*
  ```

  I've tried to figure out this  `xrandr` problem. I've noticed that some Intel hardware drivers seem to be unloaded in this excerpt of  my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file when I run `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "intel"`

  ```bsh
  [     2.919] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic root=UUID=59687312-a405-46c0-8bb7-5f4c10008c94 ro quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 acpi_backlight=vendor "acpi_osi=!Windows 2012" vt.handoff=1
  [     2.922] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
  [     2.922] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
  [     2.923] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
  [     2.923] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
  [     2.924] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
  [     2.924] (II) Unloading intel
  ```

  which I believe  [this answer](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/monitor-brightness-4175516967/) seemed to associate with this topic and might answer my question, but a bit confused where to go from here:

  > Ah, if the Intel driver is being unloaded, then that may explain why screen brightness adjustment is not working. It is likely that a basic framebuffer driver (eg fbdev or vesa) is in use.

Comment: Some other references: - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Resolution
- Can't run these commands because `xrandr` not working: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html/comment-page-4
- Maybe this would work? Couldn't quite figure it out: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-brightness-doesnt-change-on-dell-xps15-9550-with-16-04/
- Previous solutions? https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1098154
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics