# Unable to reach resolution higher than 1920x1080 60hz on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, 4k-monitor, dell-vostro

Recently I bought a 4K monitor (AOC U27U2) and after connect my Dell Vostro 3500 I was unable to set 2560x1440 or 3840x2160 via xrand (X11 windowing system). I Always get "xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed" error. I already tried the wayland windowing system but the problem is the same. My HDMI cable is 2.1 and the graphics card is Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 no driver loaded for Intel Iris Xe Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics)

Comment: I have a similar issue with a Dell Latitude 7420 with Ubuntu 22.04, however so far I only tried via the "Settings" application: I can select a higher resolution on the external 4K display (e.g. 3840x2160), but then only the top left quarter of the display area will be visible, at 2x zoom, while the rest is hidden. So, to be able to work with the monitor, I have to use 1920x1080.