# Ubuntu 22.10 Intel Iris Xe graphics doesn't work properly

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, intel-graphics, 22.10

The main problem is the impossibility of launching app project in **Qt Creator**. The application includes `.mesh` objects and lot of `.qml`. The system freezes for about 20 seconds with black screen instead of app, after building the project. The app crashes at the end.

I have this laptop:

```
    Model - VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X513EAN_K513EA
      RAM - 16.0 GiB
      CPU - 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 × 8 
 Graphics - Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

       OS - Ubuntu 22.10 64-bit (Updated from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
WindowSys - X11
   Kernel - 5.19.0-45-generic
   OpenGL - 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
```

And i've installed drivers:

```
~ inxi -G

Graphics:
Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
Device-2: Quanta USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3 driver:
  X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution:
  1: 1080x1920~60Hz 2: 1920x1080
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
```

I've tried to use different OEM kernels, like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics) post. And it worked for me before i've reinstalled the whole system. The main problem is that i don't remember what i've additionally installed before tried oem kernels, bc pure OEMs doesn't work for me now. Either 22.04 or 22.10 sys ver.

I've tried next OEM kernels on **22.04** (i don't clearly remember which one i've tried in terms of minor versions):

- 5.17.0-1003.3 **or**
- 5.17.0-1033.34 **or**
- 5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1 **or**
- 5.19.0-45.46

and

- 6.0.0-1018.18 **or**
- 6.1.0-1014.14

I've tried *5.17.0-1003-oem* kernel on **22.10**.

But nothing helped. I'm pretty sure, that i've installed something in addition in my first try. But i can't remember that endless amount of libs and repos that i've injected that time.

I really don't want to make a mess in my new OS, and i really want to resolve this problem as much clear as possible, that why i'm here. I'll be really happy to hear some opinions and info here.

Comment: FYI:   Don't forget Ubuntu 22.10 is in its last days of *supported* life, with the warning notices (*send about six weeks prior*) already out - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/

Comment: @guiverc Thank u so much. After updating to Ubuntu 23.04 with 6.3.7-060307-generic kernel, miraculously the system started working :)) I'll make a backup for now))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to @[guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc). Updating to Ubuntu 23.04 solved the problem for me.