# Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS Unable to load Intel Iris Xe Graphics

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics

Here are some info:

**linux kernel**

```
uname -r
5.15.0-91-generic
```

**lspci**

```
lspci -nnk |grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a7a0] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3c48]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a71d]
```

**dmesg**

```
dmesg |grep drm
[    2.913117] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    2.928267] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded...]
[    2.928554] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
```

**inxi**

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 2880x1800~91Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.6
```

**And I has update my oem**

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04
```

**in xorg.0.log**

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    14.466] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    14.466] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    14.466] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    14.467] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    14.467] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    16.502] (EE) No devices detected.
[    16.506] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    16.506] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    16.506] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    16.506] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

I've tried everything
but in settings->about: it still shows llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)

Comment: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/iris-xe-max-graphics/index.html

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics

Comment: Are you using 20.04 or 22.04? Question says 20.04 but it's tagged 22.04...

Comment: yeah i'm using 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: did you reboot after installing OEM kernel?

Comment: you can also consider upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu, which should have support for intel iris xe graphics out of the box

Comment: sry... My work environment requires me to use this version .it must be 20.04.5 LTS